# Change Letter Case (Assembly x86)

Tags: assembly, x86

I am new to assembly and am working on a lab of mine for an assembly class. For this part of the lab, I am required to turn strings into their opposite capitalization. So for example:

If given the string

> TheDonald

it should return

> tHEdONALD

There can be periods or other special characters,and in this case I would leave them alone. I'm also not allowed to use 32-bit registers. I should only use 8-bit version of the x86 general-purpose registers.

So far I have this:

```
void changeCase(char *string) 
{
  __asm
  {
    // BEGIN YOUR CODE HERE

    mov eax, string; // move the string into eax
    mov ecx, 0; // ecx will be counter

  BEGIN_LOOP:
    cmp byte ptr[eax + ecx * 1], 0;
    je END;

    mov al, byte ptr[eax + ecx * 1]; // get the value of the current counter

    cmp al, 65; // compare first char with A
    jl NEXT_INDEX;

    cmp al, 91;
    jl UPPER_CASE;

    cmp al, 97;
    jl NEXT_INDEX;

    cmp al, 123;
    jl LOWER_CASE;

    jmp NEXT_INDEX;

  UPPER_CASE: // if upper case, make it lower case then go to next index
    add al, 32;
    mov byte ptr[eax + ecx * 1], al;
    jmp NEXT_INDEX;
  LOWER_CASE: // if lower case, make it upper case then go to next index
    sub al, 32;
    mov byte ptr[eax + ecx * 1], al;
    jmp NEXT_INDEX;
  NEXT_INDEX:
    inc ecx;
    jmp BEGIN_LOOP;
  END:
    // END YOUR CODE HERE
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't expect people to code this or write a tutorial for you; that's not what the site is about. Get a start, then post back when you have a specific question. If you don't know where to start, you need to get help from your teacher.

Comment: Woops, edited the post again with my code

Comment: Recall that bit-5 (the sixth-bit) is the **case-bit** in 7-bit ASCII. You need only change that bit to affect the case. You can use `or` or `xor` to your advantage.

Comment: And your problem is? (that code looks actually surprisingly solid for a newcomer, it's not solving the task fully, but what it does, it does ok, as you can easily check in debugger yourself ... and then you will be probably able to better formulate your problem)

Comment: Sorry, this looked like a typical "do my homework" post. Glad to see its not.

Comment: You still need to say what you're after though however. This is pretty broad as-is. What problem are you running into?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Visual Studios is telling me that my function is incorrect. For example, with the input "TheDonald" I'm still getting "TheDonald" instead of "tHEdONALD." So am I right to assume I am storing things in my register incorrectly?

Comment: Edit: I received the correct answer after switching all my AL registers to BL. What is the difference between AL and BL registers?

Comment: @dppham1: Are you trying to kid us? The answer to your question concerning **[...]the difference between AL and BL registers** is that they are different registers. Asking that question is a clear indicator of your lack of understanding what this - your own - question is all about.

Comment: I didn't notice your overwriting of `al` destroying the `eax` pointer, but my point is, that you shouldn't run assembly, you should step into it in debugger, one instruction at time, and checking everything. That way you would probably notice early, that suddenly the characters of string are being fetched from completely different memory area, and then restarting and paying attention to `eax` `ecx` when does it get modified, would give you good hint. Still if you didn't knew before that `al` is just part of `eax`, you should probably dig a bit more into some tutorial/book, before writing code.

Answer (score 6):

The problem in your code is that you are using `al` and `eax` for two different purposes.
`al` is a part of `eax`. So if you change `al` you are actually changing the least significant byte of `eax`.
Because you're using `eax` as a base pointer you should not manipulate it, instead use a free register like `edx` and its lowest byte `dl` to perform the upcase manipulation.
If you do manipulate `al` then the pointer `eax` is going to point all over the place leading to unwanted results.

Looking deeper into the code there is no need to use both `ecx` and `eax` as pointers, one of them is enough because you can tell that you're at the end of the string by reading it's terminating zero byte.

You can easily optimize this code like so:

```
__asm{
    // BEGIN YOUR CODE HERE

    mov eax, string; // move the string into eax

BEGIN_LOOP:
    mov dl, byte ptr[eax]; //get the current char.
    test dl,dl             //is it the terminating zero?
    jz END                 //yes, we're done

    cmp dl, 'A'; // compare first char with A
    jl NEXT_INDEX;         //smaller than A, skip

    cmp dl, 'z'; //compare char with z
    jg NEXT_INDEX;        //bigger than z, skip

    xor dl,32              //'a' = 'A' + 32 and 'A' = 'a' - 32 use xor to filp that bit
    cmp dl,'z'             //Make sure we don't flip '[]\^_'
    cmovle [eax],dl        //only write when result within bounds
NEXT_INDEX:                //write back the flipped char.
    inc eax;               //next char.
    jmp BEGIN_LOOP;
END:
}
```

There are many ways to optimize it further, but I don't want to overcomplicate the issue.
Note that in x86_32 programming `eax`, `ecx` and `edx` are considered *volatile* on most platforms and some other registers might not. Therefore it's better to use only those registers if you can get away with it.
If you use other registers you have to `push` then at the routine start and `pop` them before the routine exit.

Comment: This code will also flip `[\]^_\``, so it needs one more test (after `xor dl,32` before writing using `cmp dl,'z'` again would fix it). And I would suggest to use `cmp dl,'A'` and `cmp dl,'z'` to make it obvious what is tested. And the condition jumps are wrong, either `jb + ja` or `jl + jg` would work. (and you made me feel rusty, I didn't notice the obvious `mov al,[eax...]` problem of original post :) )